# expo-image-picker translate buttons on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I need to change the text (translate to my language) when the user choose to take a photo from camera on iOS. I didn't find anything in docs. On android the buttons appear with the language configured on the device, but on iPhone the text of the buttons always appears in English. I would like to be able to change the language of these buttons

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution on a [Github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5834#issuecomment-574553123).

You can fix it by setting the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to the language of your app in the app.json config:

```
"expo":{
    ...
    "ios":{
        "infoPlist":{
            "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"de"
        }
    }
}
```

The property accepts any two-letter [ISO 639-1 language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) (like "en", "de" or "ja") or a three-letter [ISO 639-2 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes).